There are 3 apples, 4 oranges, 2 watermelons, 1 strawberry. How many ways I can choose 4 fruits so that it has at least 1 apple and 1 strawberry?
There are 3 apples, 4 oranges, 2 watermelons, 1 strawberry. How many ways I can choose 4 fruits so that it has at least 1 apple and 1 strawberry?
I don't know where I am missing the logic, there are $3C1$ ways to choose an apple, $1C1$ way to choose a strawberry and $8C2$ ways to choose $2$ from remaining $8$ fruits so $84$ ways.
But also, (1A, 1S, 2other)+(2A, 1S, 1other)+(3A, 1S) also possible so there are $64$ ways. Which one is correct?

The second argument is correct. The reason your first argument doesn't work is that it counts some possibilities more than once. For example, you could initially choose apple #1 and the strawberry, then choose orange #1 and apple #2 as your remaining two. But you could also choose apple #2 and the strawberry initially, then choose orange #1 and apple #1 for the other two. These give the same set, but you have counted them both.

Is there any way to connect both methods

@MadhanKumar You could take the first method's result and subtract off the multi-countings. Each set is counted once for each apple in it, and the number of extra counts it contributes is 1 less than that. 84 - (2 - 1) * (2A, 1S, 1other) - (3 - 1) * (3A, 1S) = 84 - 1 * 18 - 2 * 1 = 84 - 18 - 2 = 64.

Consider another way of evaluation .$\def\binom#1#2{{^{#1}\mathrm C_{#2}}}$
There are $\binom 1 1\binom{3+4+2}3$ ways to choose one strawberry and three other fruit (from among the apples, oranges, and watermellons).
There are $\binom 1 1\binom{4+2}3$ ways to choose one strawberry, no apples, and three other fruit (from among the oranges and watermellons only).
So the difference is what is required.
The count for ways to select four fruit including at least one strawberry and one apple is:
$$\binom{9}{3}-\binom63 = 64$$

PS: Also consider that by Vandermonde's convolution formula:
$\qquad\binom 93=\binom 30\binom 63~+~\binom 31\binom 62+\binom 32\binom 61+\binom 33\binom 60$

You could consider forgetting the strawberry altogether, and choose just a total of three fruits from $3$ apples ($1$ mandatory) and $6$ "others",
$\small{\text{Thus valid # of ways} =\dbinom 31\dbinom 62+\dbinom 32\dbinom 61+\dbinom 33\dbinom 60=64}$

... and indeed, this is the second alternative given by the OP, written in other terms.

@JohnBollinger: You are missing the slight improvement  by forgetting strawberries altogether.

Sorry if I'm mistaken but there are only six ways.

3 apples and 1 strawberry
2 apples, 1 strawberry, and 1 orange
2 apples, 1 strawberry, and 1 watermelon
1 apple, 1 strawberry, and 2 oranges
1 apple, 1 strawberry, and 2 watermelons
1 apple, 1 strawberry, 1 orange, and 1 watermelon


The methods shown by OP assume that the oranges are different and so are the apples and the watermelons. Most other contributors have followed OP's lead on this, as OP was trying to decide between two different answers for the same problem.

This question has a few implicit assumptions, and depending on how you handle these there can be different answers.
A. Are the fruit fungible? e.g. Is choosing the first apple the same as choosing the second apple?
B. Is the order of the fruits I choose important? e.g. Is choosing an orange and then an apple different than choosing an apple then an orange?
This gives us 4 possibilities:
If the fruit are fungible and order is not important, we get @paul-jones's answer of 6 ways.
If the fruit are fungible and order is important, we get @cj-dennis' answer of 76 ways.
If the fruit are not fungible and order is not important, we get @especially-lime's answer of 64 ways.
Finally, if the fruit are not fungible and order is important, we get 1536  ways. Which is just the 64 from above multiplied by $4!$ since each fruit is distinct. Another way of calculating this would be using k-permutations and inclusion-exclusion principle. There are $P^{10}_4$ ways of choosing among all 10 fruit, $P^9_4$ ways of choosing from the fruits without the strawberry, $P^7_4$ ways of choosing from the fruits without any of the 3 apples, and finally $P^6_4$ ways of choosing the fruits without either the strawberry or any of the apples. So our solution becomes: $P^{10}_4-P^9_4-P^7_4+P^6_4 = 1536$ (we need to add back the group we excluded twice)

Since the strawberry must be included and there must be at least one apple, that leaves two spaces to be filled. So we can ignore two of the oranges. The remaining fruits are two oranges, two apples, and two watermelons.
We could have one of each fruit:
24 x S, A, W, O
$$4!\over1!\cdot1!\cdot1!\cdot1!$$
We could have all three apples:
4 x S, A, A, A
$$4!\over3!\cdot1!$$
The only other option is two of one fruit, one strawberry, and one other fruit.
2 x 12 x S, A, A, F
and
2 x 12 x S, A, F, F
$$4!\over2!\cdot1!\cdot1!$$
There are two types of other fruit (not a strawberry or an apple). There could be one or two apples. That's $2\cdot2=4$.
So we get $24+4+4\cdot12=76$.
The answers before mine are all giving 64, so I checked this programmatically and $76$ is the correct answer.

The strawberry and three apples can only be chosen one way, as this choice uses all of them.

This answer is correct, assuming the fruit are fungible, but the order we pick them matters. Which is probably not what the author intended.

@user1176409 I laid out my logic. Please explain which part is incorrect. "Somewhere" is not helpful.
